# Balls and scales (generalization)

Tags: recreational-mathematics

A classical brain teaser is :

> You have twelve balls identical in size and appearance but one ball is an odd weight (could be either light or heavy). You have a set of balance scales. How many steps are necessary to identify the odd ball and to say whether it is light or heavy?

The answer is $3$ steps, and the the solution is easily found on the web. But what if twelve is replaced by any number $N > 2$? Is there a general way to find the optimal number of steps?

Comment: It was already asked in puzzling: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/284/n-balls-and-a-scale

Comment: See as well [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15423/optimal-algorithm-for-finding-the-odd-spheres/336224#336224) in MSE